# How do I dynamically change the source of a vimejs video with javascript?

Tags: vimejs

I'm using vime.js and trying to dynamically change the video player source video with javascript (not using any frameworks):

```
  1 (async () => {
  2   const movie = document.querySelector("a[href$='.mp4']").href;
  3   window.player = document.querySelector('vm-player');
  4 
  5   console.log('movie: ',movie);
  6 
  7   if (movie) {
  8     console.log(window.player);
  9     window.player.src = movie;
 10   }
 11 })();
```